# Bluetooth not discovering other devices

Tags: bluetooth, dell

I can't get bluetooth on my computer to discover other devices. It doesn't seem to be broken in other ways. What can I do? Any ideas? Thanks!

More details:

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS on a Dell XPS 13 9360.

rfkill list

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
10: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

dmesg | grep -i 'blue'

```
[133940.838178] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[133940.838189] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[133940.838194] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb

```
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:568b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e301 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 28bd:0914  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

bluetoothctl

```
[NEW] Controller 9C:B6:D0:E6:10:4A ChromeLinux_E714 [default]
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 9C:B6:D0:E6:10:4A Discovering: yes
```

Comment: FYI: Check your system is fully upgraded; Ubuntu 16.04.7 is what you'll see if your system is fully-upgraded.

Comment: [blueman](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/blueman) helped me with same kind of problem in the past.

Comment: @ponsfrilus I tried blueman and it showed the same thing; it also couldn't detect other devices. Did you do something specific?

Comment: @guiverc do we expect bluetooth to work by upgrading the system?

Comment: Likely it won't make a difference with bluetooth as your software stack is old & won't improve with more security fixes.. but it'll mean you have a more secure system (more known bugs fixed than your current behind-on-patches box that could be up to 18 months behind on security patches [18 months being the length of time between 16.04.6 & 16.04.7, though I'd hope you've installed some fixes since 16.04.6 came out])

Comment: @guiverc how do I upgrade the relevant parts of the software stack? It sounds like you're saying upgrading the system won't do that?

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases have to software stacks they can choose from. The first contains the GA kernel (4.4) which is supported the full life of the product; OR you can choose to use the HWE (hardware enablement stack) which upgrades to using 16.10's stack (16.04.2), then 17.04's (16.04.3), then 17.10's (16.04.4) before finally settling on 18.04's GA stack (16.04.5).. with later upgrades making no further changes (you *release-upgrade* to 18.04 for later stacks). Which stack you're using (the original or HWE) I don't know but only security fixes were involved in 18.04.7 upgrades.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack